# Laravel Eloquent: How to retrieve array of values for each column in select?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a 'clients_campaigns' table that has three columns. User_id, company_id and campaign_id. I want to get a list of all company_id's and campaign id's that have a specific user_id. With these two lists I will search through two other tables, Companies and Campaigns. By using each list, I will find the names associated to the id's.

I am unsure how to create two lists that'll contain each type of id's. Below is my attempt and the code I have so far.

```
            $ids = \DB::table('clients_campaigns')->select('company_id','campaign_id')
                                                  ->where('user_id',$request->user_id)
                                                  ->pluck('company_id','campaign_id');
            if($ids !== null){
                //use those id's to retrieve the company names and campaign names
               Company::select('name')->whereIn('id', ...);
               Campaign::select('name')->whereIn('id',...);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do it this way you are not far off but you really don't need the first `pluck` since there will only be 3 fields anyway. You can then `pluck` the `company_id` and `campaign_id` columns separately to be used in the next 2 queries:

```
$ids = DB::table('clients_campaigns')
    ->where('user_id', $request->user_id)
    ->get(['company_id', 'campaign_id']);

if ($ids->notEmpty()) {
    $companyNames = Company::whereIn('id', $ids->pluck('company_id'))
        ->pluck('name');
    $campaignNames = Campaign::whereIn('id', $ids->pluck('campaign_id'))
        ->pluck('name');
}
```

If you used pluck on the first query you would have a list keyed by `campaign_id` then you would have to use just the keys for the `Campaign` query and just the values for the `Company` query.

You also have the option of passing query objects to the `whereIn` calls instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) When you say if I really want to do it this way, do you mean to say there's a better way I could be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Taking your current example, you could retrive the results from the first query into a Collection and then use the collection to extract your results for each subsequent query.

Putting this into practice would look like this:

```
$ids = \DB::table('clients_campaigns')->select('company_id','campaign_id')
    ->where('user_id',$request->user_id)
    ->get();
    ->pluck('company_id','campaign_id');

if ($ids->count()) {
    //use those id's to retrieve the company names and campaign names
    Company::select('name')->whereIn('id', $ids->pluck('company_id'));
    Campaign::select('name')->whereIn('id', $ids->pluck('campaign_id'));
}
```